# How can I manually Installing DBD-Oracle 1.17 in ActivePerl on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl, dbd

After installing Active Perl 5.8.8 Build 822 on WindowsXP, I do not see DBD-Oracle in "View All Packages" of Perl Package Manager. 
The CPAN location of the same is http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Oracle-1.17/,
but I don't know the process to manually install this tar(DBD-Oracle-1.17.tar.gz) in ActivePerl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Oracle Instant Client for Windows.

Do you really need to use ActivePerl 5.8.8 as the process is easier in 5.8.9.827 and above. Usually you just do:

```
cpan P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.17.tar.gz
```

and if you don't have Microsoft Visual C on your path it downloads MinGW and installs it. I think if you are before 5.8.9 of ActivePerl you might have to install MinGW yourself with:

```
ppm install MinGW
```

but I think in 5.8.8 you will have to download, install and configure MinGW and dmake manually though, so you may not want to bother...

BTW, Do you really need to use DBD::Oracle 1.17? That is really old now. 1.26 is the latest.

Comment: I meant to add that there are various README.xxx files for DBD::Oracle that might help you. You can view them at cpan.

Comment: yes I need to use these specific versions of ActivePerl and DBD for a task, I think I do not have Visual C installed. I'll try the steps you mentioned to see if I can get it installed.  Thanks for you reply.